# How can I remove the empty line that keeps getting added at the end of the two files in python?

Tags: python

Here is my code:-

```
f= open("Passes.py", "r+")
m=open("money.py","r+")
passes= {}
init={}
initial=0
import time
print "Welcome to the virtual banking system"
time.sleep(0.5)
user=raw_input("Would you like to create a new account? 'Y/N'").lower()
if user== "y":
  new_user= raw_input("Create a username:")
  new_pass= raw_input("Create a password:")
  p= passes[new_user]= new_user + ":" + new_pass
  f.write(str(p+"\n"))
  ask=raw_input("Would you like to sign into your account? 'Y/N'").lower()
  if ask=="y":
    user_in=raw_input("Enter your username:")
    if user_in==new_user:
      pass_in=raw_input("Enter your password:")
      if pass_in==new_pass:
        print "Welcome to your account" + " " + new_user
        useropt=raw_input("Would you like to view your balance- enter 1, deposit money- enter 2, withdraw money- enter 3 or exit- enter 4:")
        if useropt=="1":
          print "Your balance is:", initial
        if useropt=="2":
          amountdep= int(raw_input("How much money would you like to deposit?:"))
          initial+=amountdep
          print "Thanks. Your new balance is:", initial
        if useropt=="3":
          amountwith=int(raw_input("How much would you like to withdraw?:"))
          initial-=amountwith
          print "Your balance is:", initial
        i=init[new_user]=str(initial)
        m.write(str(i)+"\n")
      else:
        print "Password not valid"

    else:
      print "Username does not exist"

  else:
    print "Thanks for using the virtual bank."

else:
  user2=raw_input("Do you have an existing account? 'Y/N'").lower()
  if user2=="y":
    existing_user=raw_input("Enter your username:")
    exisitng_pass=raw_input("Enter your password:")
    for passwords in f:
      if passwords==existing_user+":"+exisitng_pass:
        print "Welcome to your account" + " " + existing_user
        useropt2=raw_input("Would you like to view your balance- enter 1, deposit money- enter 2, withdraw money- enter 3 or exit- enter 4:")
        if useropt2=="1":
          for info in m:
            print "Your balance is:", info
        if useropt2=="2":
          amountdep= int(raw_input("How much money would you like to deposit?:"))
          for info in m:
            a=int(info)+int(amountdep)
            print "Thanks. Your balance is:", int(a)
          m.close()
          m= open("money.py", "w")
          m.write(str(a))
        if useropt2=="3":
          amountwith=int(raw_input("How much would you like to withdraw?:"))
          for info in m:
            t=int(info)-int(amountwith)
            print "Thanks. Your balance is:", t
          m.close()
          m=open("money.py","w")
          m.write(str(t))
```

I would like to know how I can remove the empty line at the end of each file which gets added after putting "\n". I think that this might be able to be solved using str.rstrip(), but do not know how. Thanks

Comment: Do not name your data files with `.py` extension. It belongs only to Python programs. Also, your code is duplicated, which makes reading and understanding it very hard. You must separate account creation from all other operations.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but '\n' basically stands for 'newline'. If you see an empty line in and text editor is actually the '\n' characters thats getting display this way. In your case simply don't write the very last '\n' to the file and you should no longer see the empty line. As you mentioned yourself, you could use str.rstrip("\n") to solve the problem.

Comment: You're always writing your data with linefeeds on the ends, so of course there's always a linefeed.

Comment: @Share - Stripping off the linefeed rather than just not concatenating it in the first place seems a bit silly...

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I totally agree. I just mentioned it, because Sam123 addressed it in his question.